# Why is Wufoo PHP API not working?

Tags: php, api, wufoo

**UPDATE:** I've found that this issue is related to my hosting setup somehow. The code is hosted on a DV server by Media Temple, however I placed the exact same code on a GS Media Temple server and it worked as expected. So any ideas as to what could be different between the two?

---

Wondering if anyone can shed some light on why I can't get this API call to work. Just trying to get form entry data. If I paste the URL to the JSON into my browser, it displays as you'd expect but in this call I can't get any server response.

```
<?php


$api_uri_1 = "https://eastbankads.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/z1qh9i4b1qg5qa6/entries.json";

function wufoo_api($api_uri) {
  $curl = curl_init($api_uri);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'MY-API-KEY:password');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Wufoo Sample Code');
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl);

  if ($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
    $results = json_decode($response, true);
    return $results;
  } else {
    $results = 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);
    return $results;
  }
}

$result1 = wufoo_api($api_uri_1);

?>
```

I've checked & doubled checked my API key. Here's a link to my test page and the output that's given from the code:

http://resources.worldoftile.net/wufoo-perfect-project-entries/

Or, this is what is output on that page:

```
Array ( 
  [url] => https://eastbankads.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/z1qh9i4b1qg5qa6/entries.json 
  [content_type] => 
  [http_code] => 0 
  [header_size] => 0 
  [request_size] => 132 
  [filetime] => -1 
  [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
  [redirect_count] => 0 
  [total_time] => 0.068676 
  [namelookup_time] => 2.2E-5 
  [connect_time] => 0.009197 
  [pretransfer_time] => 0 
  [size_upload] => 0 
  [size_download] => 0 
  [speed_download] => 0 
  [speed_upload] => 0 
  [download_content_length] => -1 
  [upload_content_length] => 0 
  [starttransfer_time] => 0 
  [redirect_time] => 0.068764 
  [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
  [primary_ip] => 75.98.93.66 
  [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like trying to do even a simple "telnet to port 80"-type check from the server to that url's server?  as a real world analogy: even if your car is in 100% perfect condition, doesn't mean you can magically drive over the bridge that was washed out the previous evening. so check if you're allowed to make outgoing requests from your server, or if that url is blacklisting your server, etc...

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, I will check that. I did check another URL, https://www.yahoo.com, and got a normal http 200 response. I'm going to contact the host - Media Temple - and see if they have any ideas.

Comment: @MarcB  After some searching around about the simple check you mentioned...I'm afraid I don't know how to do that. I was able to use an online Ping test to test the domain https://eastbankads.wufoo.com/ and didn't have any problems.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the below line will fix this issue.

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

Comment: And why would it fix that? The OP indicated that it is related to their specific network setup. How does this change influence that?

Comment: Maybe because I had the same issue and worked for me.